# Passing models to Bootstrap for Ember Popovers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

To anyone using [Bootstrap for Ember](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/popover) components and could help figure out something.

How can I pass a model to the component when using {{bs-bind-popover}}

```
<div {{bs-bind-popover templPop}}>Show popover</div>
```

In the controller I used the code from the example:

```
templPop: Ember.Object.create({
  firstName: 'numbers',
  title: 'Popover with Template',
  template: 'numbers:<ul>' +
          '{{#each val in content.numbers}}' +
          '   <li>{{val}}</li>' + '{{/each}}' +
          '</ul>',
  content: {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3]
  }
```

})

What would be the way to pass a model or other arguments to bs-bind-popover so I could use them in templPop content and template?

Something like {{bs-bind-popover templPop model}}

Comment: Did you find a way to do this at all?

Comment: No, at that moment no, I postponed that for a couple of months, it wasn't critical to the app. There were some updates to the project in the meantime, need to update and see if it works now.

Comment: I haven't used the Bootsrap for Ember, but as per my understanding I think in Ember you can pass the model from route to contoller directly. So you can try passing the required model directly from your route to component. Hope it helped a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `templPop` property to a computed property:

```js
 templPop:function(){

     return Ember.Object.create({

      firstName: 'numbers',
      title: 'Popover with Template',
      template: 'numbers:<ul>' +
              '{{#each item in content.model}}' +
              '   <li>{{model.property}}</li>' + '{{/each}}' +
              '</ul>',
      content: {
        model: this.get('model')
        }
     });
 }.property('model'),
```